# strcmp is not working expectedly in PHP

Tags: php

I am setting a session variable in a php file as:

```
$_SESSION['PageFrom']="check_login_test.php";
```

Later on the control is transferred to another php file via a form and post. The relevant code in the 2nd file is:

```
session_start();
$from=trim($_SESSION['PageFrom']);
pageFrom("check_login_test.php",$from);
die('I came here');
```

Now pageFrom is a function that should have compared the strings and said so. The original function was simply

```
function oldPageFrom($page,$from)
{
  $page= trim($page);
  $from=trim($from);
  if (strcmp($page,$from)!==0)
   {
      echo 'The pages are not same';
   }
}
```

Since it did not work as expected, I tried to debug the same and output as much as I can (This changed the old function, but now reveals some things interesting) . The function is

```
function pageFrom($page,$from)
{
 echo '<br/>$page='.$page;
 echo '<br/>$from='.$from;
 $m=trim($page);
 $n=trim($from);
 echo "<br/>TrimmedPage=$m<br/>TrimmedFrom=$n";
 $k= strcmp($m,$n);
 echo '$k='.$k;
 if($k !==0);
   {

     $i=strlen($from);
     $j=strlen($page);
        if ($i==$j)
            {
             echo "<br/>The string lengths are Equal $i=$j";
             die('Equal in unequal');
            }
        else
            {
              echo "<br/>The string lengths are UnEqual $i<>$j";
              die('UnEqual in unequal');
            }

  }

 echo 'Works as expected. They are equal'; die('equal');
 }
```

Strangely I get the following as output:

$page=check_login_test.php

$from=check_login_test.php

TrimmedPage=check_login_test.php

TrimmedFrom=check_login_test.php$k=0

The string lengths are Equal 20=20Equal in unequal

So the questions are:
(1)I have trimmed the strings. They are equal and of the same length. Strcmp returns 0. Then why does it enter the loop if($k !==0) at all? Note: no luck in ($k!=0) too.

Comment: Thank you Ijacqu. Now it works as expected . Solved.  That ; did take quite some time. Thanks a lot once again. ( Glad that strcmp is not having problems!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the following code:

```
if($k !==0);
   {
```

The semi-colon (`;`) terminates the `if` clause and the subsequent `{ }` block won't have any effect. Remove the `;` after `if` and it will work as it should, i.e. this code below

```
if($k !==0)
   {
```